# How to specify non-default shared-library path in GCC Linux? Getting "error while loading shared libraries" when running

Tags: gcc, linker, shared-libraries

There is a laptop on which I have no root privilege.

onto the machine I have a library installed using `configure --prefix=$HOME/.usr` .

after that, I got these files in `~/.usr/lib` :

```
libXX.so.16.0.0
libXX.so.16
libXX.so
libXX.la
libXX.a
```

when I compile a program that invokes one of function provided by the library with this command :
`gcc XXX.c -o xxx.out -L$HOME/.usr/lib -lXX`

xxx.out was generated without warning, but when I run it error like this was thrown:

`./xxx.out: error while loading shared libraries: libXX.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` , though `libXX.so.16` resides there.

my clue-less assumption is that `~/.usr/lib` wasn't searched when xxx.out is invoked.
but what can I do to specify path of .so , in order that xxx.out can look there for .so file?

An addition is when I feed `-static` to gcc, another error happens like this:

```
undefined reference to `function_proviced_by_the_very_librar'
```

It seems `.so` does not matter even though `-L` and `-l` are given to gcc.
what should I do to build a usable exe with that library?

---

#### For other people who has the same question as I did

I found [a useful article at tldp](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/index.html) about this.

It introduces static/shared/dynamic loaded library, as well as some example code to use them.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve that:

- Use `-rpath` linker option:

`gcc XXX.c -o xxx.out -L$HOME/.usr/lib -lXX -Wl,-rpath=/home/user/.usr/lib`

- Use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable - put this line in your `~/.bashrc` file:

  `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/.usr/lib`

This will work even for a pre-generated binaries, so you can for example download some packages from the [debian.org](http://packages.debian.org/), unpack the binaries and shared libraries into your home directory, and launch them without recompiling.

For a quick test, you can also do (in bash at least):

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/.usr/lib ./xxx.out
```

which has the advantage of not changing your library path for everything else.

Answer (score 4):

Should it be `LIBRARY_PATH` instead of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. 
gcc checks for `LIBRARY_PATH` which can be seen with `-v` option

Comment: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not for GCC, it is for runtime library loader (/lib/ld-linux.so.2 etc). GCC might not be installed at all for `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to work.