# add armadillo libraries to g++ compiler in linux

Tags: c++, linux, unix, gcc, armadillo

I am trying to install a C++ library ([armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/)) in a unix cluster where I do not have root permissions.

I managed to compile the C++ libraries without user permissions by running the following make command:

```
make install DESTDIR=my_usr_dir
```

But then in the armadillo readme file it says:

where "my_usr_dir" is for storing C++ headers and library files. Make sure your C++ compiler is configured to use the sub-directories present within this directory.

The compiler the armadillo uses to install the libraries is gcc-4.8.1. I am not sure where the compiler was installed but it's loaded when I start my session in the unix cluster.

After installing armadillo I am trying to compile open source code that uses the armadillo libraries.  This open source code also has a makefile.

However, when I go to the open source code and I type in:

```
make
```

it calls g++.  How can I make sure g++ will recognize the armadillo libraries previously installed in my_usr_dir?

Currently I get the following error if I go to src and then type make:

```
opencode.cpp:28:21: fatal error: armadillo: No such file or directory
 #include <armadillo>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [mmcollapse] Error 1
```

Comment: You should have some basic understanding before asking on SO. Did you ever read the man pages of gcc (`man gcc`)? In particular the sections about `-I`, `-l`, and `-L`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use

```
 alias gcc="gcc -I./my_usr_dir/include -L./my_usr_dir/lib"
```

and so on in your `.bashrc` file. In that way, whenever you invoke gcc on the command line, the flags will be added before every other argument you enter on the command line

Comment: the problem ended up being slightly more complicated, please let me know if you have some suggestions...

Comment: I tried: alias g++="g++ -I.<myuserdir>/include -L.<myuserdir>/lib" but I still get the error.

Comment: have you tried `#include <armadillo.h>`? I think only the standard headers don't have the extension

Comment: thanks your answer got me the idea, I just changed the makefile and it seems to work now...

Answer (score 1):

I think the readme file refers to the usage of the library headers and library files from applications. For those to be useful, the compiler/linker/loader (usually all driven by the "compiler") have to know where to find them. The compiler always looks in some default directories, such as `/usr/include` (for headers) and `/usr/lib/` (for libraries), but they require root permission to write into. However, you can tell the compiler with the flag `-I`*directory* to search in directory *directory* for headers. For libraries use `-l` and `-L` (check the manual page of your compiler). You may also need to consider the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LD_RUN_PATH` environment variables, if you're using dynamic linking (shared object files).

Comment: please refer to the new question, there I explain all the process... maybe i did something wrong but I keep getting the error.

Comment: It seems you didn't read my answer. It explained exactly what you have to do: use the `-I` and `-L` compiler flags. It also said you should read the compiler man page (`man gcc`), where all this is explained in more detail. Did you?

Answer (score 1):

This question looks similar to

> [How to specify non-default shared-library path in GCC Linux? Getting "error while loading shared libraries" when running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835108/specify-non-default-shared-library-path-in-gcc-linux)

If you dont want to change the .bashrc

use -rpath as suggested in the post above.

> gcc XXX.c -o xxx.out -Lmy_usr_dir -lXX -Wl,-rpath=my_usr_dir

-L is for static linking
-rpath for adding the directory to the linker search path

more on -rpath here

> [I don't understand -Wl,-rpath -Wl,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6562403/i-dont-understand-wl-rpath-wl)

Dont bother to upvote the answer because this is really not an answer. I would have commented but i could not locate the add comment for your post.

Comment: thanks, the problem is slightly different as previously states, i edited the q

Comment: -I/location/of/header/file  as suggested by @Roberto should solve your problem