# Some times : error while loading shared libraries: libboost_serialization.so.1.66.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, boost, pthreads

There are many question asked regarding this issue [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835108/how-to-specify-non-default-shared-library-path-in-gcc-linux-getting-error-whil).

I have the library in the path as mentioned in the above link.

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/mydir/boost_1_66_0/stage/lib
```

I am using `eclipse oxygen`, where I added the libraries of boost and pthread like

```
-l
boost_serialization
pthread
```

and included the linker path `-L /home/mydir/boost_1_66_0/stage/lib` and compiler path `-l /home/mydir/boost_1_66_0`. When I test the program of two files for example `thread.cpp` and `thread.h`, it is working fine. But when I include more files it gives me the errror

```
error while loading shared libraries: libboost_serialization.so.1.66.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I am not sure what is going wrong with more files and gives the linking error.

**Edit**

I tried using `makefile`, which has something like

```
CXX     = g++
DEBUG   = -g

CXXFLAGS  = -Wall $(DEBUG) -std=c++17 -boost_serialization -pthread
```

and it goes on compiling and end with

```
Building target: Test
Invoking: Cross G++ Linker
g++ -std=c++17 -L/home/mydir/boost_1_66_0/stage/lib -o "Test"  ./decodenumbers.o ./encodechars.o ./help.o ./index.o ./inputparameters.o ./loadindex.o ./main.o ./match.o ./output.o ./readfastqfiles.o ./report.o ./reversestrand.o ./samformat.o ./saveindex.o ./time.o ./trimreads.o ./validate.o ./version.o   -lboost_serialization -lpthread
Finished building target: Test
```

When I run, it gives the same issue.

Comment: @Hamed I have already mentioned that I have the library in the path.

Comment: Try compiling with the flag `-pthread` rather than link the `pthread` library directly

Comment: @Galik I tried using `makefile`, please check the edit above.

Comment: @Galik I am surprised to see this morning that the running of the code does not complain about anything (when I tried to look into the issue after a couple of days). Maybe my machine wanted me to take some rest or machine needed some rest, not sure. Anyway happy, but not sure about the issue.