# use alternative shared object in c

Tags: c, dynamic-library, shared-objects

I have this:

```c
#include "/home/tom/scripts/c/headers/stdio.h"
#include "/home/tom/scripts/c/headers/stdlib.h"
int main()
{
       printf("Hi there\n");
       exit(0);
}
```

compiling it it with:

```
gcc hello.c -L/home/tom/scripts/c/ -lc -o hello
```

and I get:

```
linux-gate.so.1 (0xb7769000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb7571000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb776b000)
```

I've compiled a bunch a programs in c successfuly but I want the binary to point the shared object `ld-linux.so.2` located on /home/tom/scripts/c not to pick the library on the system by default.

Comment: `and I get:` that looks like `ldd` output, not from `gcc`. Read `man ld.so`.

Comment: @KamilCuk, You do know the text on the console is not the only output created by gcc, right? The text describes the executable file gotten from gcc.

Comment: @KamilCuk, I'm not seeing anything relevant in `man ld.so` on my GNU/Linux (Ubuntu) system. To what were you referring?

Comment: I don't know, I'm pretty lost. I want the system (if possible) look for the shared object on that folder instead of `/lib/i386-linux-gnu/` in my case. I have two libraries with the same name. Can two binaries look up for different .so with the same name? that's what I mean. I know can be a silly question, I'm a noob in c.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify non-default shared-library path in GCC Linux? Getting "error while loading shared libraries" when running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8835108/how-to-specify-non-default-shared-library-path-in-gcc-linux-getting-error-whil)

Comment: @ralfhtp thanks, that solves my issues